# Justify Content CSS property isn't working on classes

Tags: html, css, frontend, nav

I'm learning frontend web development and designing my own portfolio. I've stumbled across an issue regarding justify-content and align-item CSS properties. They don't seem to work on my classes.

[Protfolio Demo with current CSS & HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtL4P.png)

Here is the relevant code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

body {
  font-family: roboto;
  background-repeat: space;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 20vh;
}

.space1 {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.nav-logo {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.empty-space1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}

.space2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.empty-space2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<nav>
  <div class="space1">
    <div class="nav-logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="empty-space1">lorem
      <!--empty space-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="space2">
    <div class="empty-space2">lorem
      <!--empty space-->
    </div>
    <div class="nav-links">lorem
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Would you please tell me why is this not working and How can I solve the issue?

Thank you
:)

Comment: Hi @ThinkTank ! Can you describe what exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to align the text to the middle? Some explaining of the issue itself will help a lot in trying to answer you question! [please read this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello @Thatkookooguy , sorry for causing the confusion. Yes, I'm actually trying to send the navigation links like "About Me" etc into the centre of the div. But somehow the CSS properties aren't applying to it.

Comment: have you tried putting the justify content on the `nav-links` div?

Comment: hey, @coder, I did try it, but it only put the word "Lorem" into the centre and not the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to align to the center using `align-items` and `justify-content`, you need to apply it to **the direct container of your content**.

Also, your `ul` element had a `height: 100%` even though there where more text before it. so I removed that so it won't overflow the container.

```css
/* ADDITION */

.centered-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* END */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

body {
  font-family: roboto;
  background-repeat: space;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
}

.space1 {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.nav-logo {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.empty-space1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}

.space2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.empty-space2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  /* REMOVED! */
  /* height: 100%; */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.nav-links ul a {
  margin: 0 .1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<nav>
  <div class="space1">
    <div class="centered-content nav-logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="centered-content empty-space1">lorem
      <!--empty space-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="space2">
    <div class="centered-content empty-space2">lorem
      <!--empty space-->
    </div>
    <div class="centered-content nav-links">lorem
      <ul class="centered-content">
        <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Notice that I moved the `justify-content: space-evenly;` from `.nav-links ul li a` to `.nav-links ul li`, which is our **content's container**. So we want to justify its content to space evenly.

For safety (to make sure they don't touch even on small screens), you can add a margin between each element to separate them as well:

```css
.nav-links ul a {
  margin: 0 .1em;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Thatkookooguy, thanks a lot, the alignment issue is resolved but the issue with spacing between the nav link still persists.

Comment: @ThinkTank what kind of alignment are you trying to get in that area specifically? should they appear on top of each other? like a list (each item in a new row)?

Comment: no I just want to have spaces between them, I know I could directly use &ThickSpace; or other such tags in between the <a> tag but I want to know why it isn't working with "Justify-content: space-evenly" as you provided in the code.
Regards.

Comment: @ThinkTank made the "space evenly" thing work in my answer with a little explanation at the end. hope that helped!

Comment: that works. Thanks a lot. :)
Also the answer is upvoted and answer is marked.